# Ctrl +C can't kill the node

Tags: ros, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

However , I wrote a UDP_server to keep receive massage ,and  the receive funcion is in the while(ros::ok()),but when I press ctrl +C , the process doesn't shut down . what's going wrong ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258041/ctrl-+c-can%27t-kill-the-node/) by [Tomas yuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/29377/tomas-yuan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2017-03-28

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [takahashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/23199/takahashi/) on 2017-03-28**:
please post the code, it's hard to help debugging without any..

**Comment by [Tomas yuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/29377/tomas-yuan/) on 2017-03-28**:
thank you，it has been sloved

**Comment by [jiashiwei](https://answers.ros.org/users/26780/jiashiwei/) on 2017-07-05**:
hi! I meet the same problem with you , can i have chance to know how you solved this problem?  thank you a lot !

**Comment by [Tomas yuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/29377/tomas-yuan/) on 2017-07-05**:
施佳伟？    程序阻塞了，用select函数可以解决。

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-05**:
@Tomas yuan: could you please only use English on ROS Answers? Thanks.

**Comment by [jiashiwei](https://answers.ros.org/users/26780/jiashiwei/) on 2017-07-06**:
您好！ 没想到你也是中国人啊 呵呵。 我叫贾士伟。 根据你的指点，没找到select函数啊，你是在哪找的呢？ 我用的是boost 里的udp

**Comment by [Tomas yuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/29377/tomas-yuan/) on 2017-07-06**:
Hi,nice to meet you .Boost library may not contain the `select`function,you can use `async_read()` to work in asynchronous way for data reading .Here is [boost::ASIO的异步方式](http://blog.csdn.net/zhuky/article/details/5364685) .And if you donnot use the boost class , you can directly use socket for udp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The process has been blocked，so you cannot use Ctrl c to kill the node. However, it is not recommended to allow the program to work in a blocked state.You can use function  `select`when you use  `read`to get some data in UDP or  serial port process.

---

Originally posted by [Tomas yuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/29377/tomas-yuan/) with karma: 56 on 2017-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Despite the possible way to kill an app by invoking the Ctrl +C in the termina, that is not the proper way to finish/dispose a living node, you should do instead:

> $rosnode kill *yourNodeName*

the reason is that Ctrl +C may not give the chance to the node to dispose itself properly, before the node dies it must isself disconnect from Master, release resources, etc etc which may not happen by doing just Ctrl +C

btw

> $rosnode cleanup

will guide you diagnose, and purge those zombie nodes

---

Originally posted by [ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ](https://answers.ros.org/users/29728/%CF%86xoc%C4%99-%EC%9B%83-%D0%BFepe%C3%BApa-%E3%83%84/) with karma: 424 on 2017-03-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2017-03-28**:
As far as I know, roscpp installs a signal handler for Ctrl-C, which will do a clean exit. I'd guess rospy and other client libraries do the same.

**Comment by [SorinV](https://answers.ros.org/users/30485/sorinv/) on 2017-09-19**:
Having just a

```
while(1)
{
    printf("something \n");
}
```

in main blocks the node, cannot kill it with anything else than System Monitor or linux command line. Any ROS providen method does not work.

It only hides it from the ROS environment, but the process is still there.

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2017-11-17**:
yes, you'd need to do `while(ros::ok()){ ... }`. My understanding is, that the ros signal handler will make ros::ok() fail, instead of killing the program. This way you can stop whereever convenient. Btw: Ctrl+Backslash will kill your program in the shell, but without any chance for cleanup.